# is the half-life of a radioactive isotope dependent on the type of radiation it releases (alpha/beta/gamma)?

Tags: radioactivity

I understand the term half-life but I am not sure if the type of radiation it emits is a factor affecting an isotopes half-life

Comment: Yes it is the primary factor.

Comment: There are isotopes with long or short half lives for either alpha or beta decay. So, no, one type of decay is not intrinsically faster or slower than another.